# Cleaning up git repositories

Tags: git

We have a git repo of 500MB large. Now it turns out that somewhere in the history a few unneeded files of 50MB - 75MB were added and removed after. To make the repo smaller I've decided to rewrite the history by removing the files from their commits.

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Projects/largefile.xml" HEAD

git push -f
```

The files are gone indeed but it seems the .git directory has not gotten smaller. Does it help to do this? How can we make a git repo as small as possible?

Comment: Does [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) help?